# Heroku command error .local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 21:

Tags: heroku

My heroku toolbelt had been working fine until last week that it's giving me this error on all heroku commands.

```
$ heroku run console -a abc
/Users/songserm/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 21: /Users/songserm/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/node: No such file or directory
/Users/songserm/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 21: /Users/songserm/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

I didn't know that my heroku has been auto upgraded, but what has changed is I installed heroku-vi addon around the time. Not sure if it's the case.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Noted that I installed heroku on my Mac using homebrew.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

### Cause:

This also happened to me, the client auto-updated but didn't do so properly:

```
heroku run console
heroku-cli: Updating to 6.11.14-c5f9179... 12.9 MB/12.9 MB
/Users/steves/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 21: /Users/steves/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/node: No such file or directory
/Users/steves/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 21: /Users/steves/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

### Solution:

The resolution was to re-install the client using the following (as found here https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/485):

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku/client
```

I then checked using the status command and it re-installed correctly:

```
heroku status
heroku-cli: Updating to 6.11.14-c5f9179... 12.9 MB/12.9 MB
Migrating Heroku CLI v5 plugins... done
Apps:      No known issues at this time.
Data:      No known issues at this time.
Tools:     No known issues at this time.
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I have no idea why I didn't use ~ originally.

Comment: I ran into this after updating Mac OS to High Sierra. I was glad to find this quick fix!

Comment: Great! Nice catch! :)

Answer (score 10):

#### [Heroku-error-Not a directory](https://qiita.com/jpena930/items/d0dd9c86b6007b8e4264)

**Not a directory Error when executing Heroku commands**

```
heroku
▸   stat /User/xxx/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: not a directory
▸   fork/exec /User/xxx/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: not a directory
```

**Solution is to remove previous directory**

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku/client
```

Comment: Not an answer to the original question but it solved my problem. +1

Comment: works perfect for me. Heroku updated the client after I removed the folder and ran `heroku status`.

Comment: I had that issue while updating from 7.0.12 to 7.22.7 and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround for me was to remove this file.

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku
```

And I was able to acces heroku console easily.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said the solution is:

deleting the heroku client with the following console command:

`rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku/plugins`

But if you continue having problems you have to delete the heroku plugins folder:

`rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku/plugins`

Then you can excecute the command
`heroku status`

To reinstall correctly

> $ heroku status
>
> heroku-cli: Updating to 6.99.0-ec9edad... 12.8 MB/12.8 MB
>
> Apps:      No known issues at this time.
>
> Data:      No known issues at this time.
>
> Tools:     No known issues at this time.